# string.translate() with unicode data in python

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary

I have 3 API's that return json data to 3 dictionary variables. I am taking some of the values from the dictionary to process them. I read the specific values that I want to the list `valuelist`. One of the steps is to remove the punctuation from them. I normally use `string.translate(None, string.punctuation)` for this process but because the dictionary data is unicode I get the error:

```
    wordlist = [s.translate(None, string.punctuation)for s in valuelist]
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Is there a way around this? Either by encoding the unicode or a replacement for `string.translate`?

Comment: `s.encode('utf-8').translate(None, string.punctuation)` worked for me.

Comment: @Suzana_K Thank you! This was the simplest solution for me.

Comment: related: [Remove punctuation from Unicode formatted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The translate method work differently on Unicode objects than on byte-string objects:

```
>>> help(unicode.translate)

S.translate(table) -> unicode

Return a copy of the string S, where all characters have been mapped
through the given translation table, which must be a mapping of
Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or None.
Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None
are deleted.
```

So your example would become:

```py
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
word_list = [s.translate(remove_punctuation_map) for s in value_list]
```

Note however that `string.punctuation` only contains ASCII punctuation. Full Unicode has many more punctuation characters, but it all depends on your use case.

Comment: [`dict.fromkeys(map(ord, string.punctuation))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/4279)

Comment: this is by far the best of all the answers on here. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed that string.translate is deprecated. Since you are removing punctuation, not actually translating characters, you can use the re.sub function.

```
    >>> import re

    >>> s1="this.is a.string, with; (punctuation)."
    >>> s1
    'this.is a.string, with; (punctuation).'
    >>> re.sub("[\.\t\,\:;\(\)\.]", "", s1, 0, 0)
    'thisis astring with punctuation'
    >>>
```

Comment: the translate function works great in python 2.7 and is computationally faster than REGEX. I may have no other option though. Thanks

Comment: The module function `string.translate` is deprecated in favor of the method `str.translate`, the `translate` method (which OP is using) is still usable.

Answer (score 3):

In this version you can relatively make one's letters to other

```
def trans(to_translate):
    tabin = u'привет'
    tabout = u'тевирп'
    tabin = [ord(char) for char in tabin]
    translate_table = dict(zip(tabin, tabout))
    return to_translate.translate(translate_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python `re` module allows to use [a function as a replacement argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), which should take a `Match` object and return a suitable replacement. We may use this function to build a custom character translation function:

```
import re

def mk_replacer(oldchars, newchars):
    """A function to build a replacement function"""
    mapping = dict(zip(oldchars, newchars))
    def replacer(match):
        """A replacement function to pass to re.sub()"""
        return mapping.get(match.group(0), "")
    return replacer
```

An example. Match all lower-case letters (`[a-z]`), translate 'h' and 'i' to 'H' and 'I' respectively, delete other matches:

```
>>> re.sub("[a-z]", mk_replacer("hi", "HI"), "hail")
'HI'
```

As you can see, it may be used with short (incomplete) replacement sets, and it may be used to delete some characters.

A Unicode example:

```
>>> re.sub("[\W]", mk_replacer(u'\u0435\u0438\u043f\u0440\u0442\u0432', u"EIPRTV"), u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442')
u'PRIVET'
```

Answer (score 1):

As I stumbled upon the same problem and Simon's answer was the one that helped me to solve my case, I thought of showing an easier example just for clarification:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

And then for the translation, say you'd like to remove '@' and '\r' characters:

```
remove_chars_map = defaultdict()
remove_chars_map['@'] = None
remove_chars_map['\r'] = None

new_string = old_string.translate(remove_chars_map)
```

And an example:

> old_string = "word1@\r word2@\r word3@\r"
>
> new_string = "word1 word2 word3"
>
> '@' and '\r' removed